# Alternative algorithm for radius zipcode search?

Tags: algorithm, search, formula, zipcode, radius

I have a query to an sql database to find all of the matching zipcodes within a given radius from a given zipcode (the db table contains longitude and latitude information).

I was using this algorithm that I found here on stackoverflow:

$sql = 'SELECT distinct(ZipCode) FROM zipcode  WHERE (3958*3.1415926*sqrt((Latitude-'.$lat.')*(Latitude-'.$lat.') + cos(Latitude/57.29578)*cos('.$lat.'/57.29578)*(Longitude-'.$lon.')*(Longitude-'.$lon.'))/180) <= '.$radius.';';

It functions, but I'm finding that the results are not exactly as expected. For example, if I do a 40 mile radius search from 11572 (Oceanside, NY), it doesn't return a number of Manhattan zip codes (i.e., 10023) that are clearly within that 40 mile radius.

I'm hoping that somebody might have an alternative approach?

thanks, Mark

Comment: try: where sqrt(pow(Latitute - '$.lat', 2) + pow(Longitude -'.$lon', 2)) <= '$.radius'

Comment: I might guess the problems is that this is measuring zip code centers within the 40 mile radius - and you probably want and zip codes with and area in a 40 mile radius. Does that sound possible?

Comment: I gave that a shot, nmtuan, but it returned an enormous list well beyond the given radius of 40 miles and caused a fatal timeout exception.

Comment: Thanks, gbtimmon. I get what you're saying, but I don't think that's the issue . A 40 mile radius from 11572 encompasses and goes so far beyond Manhattan that the missing zip codes, center or otherwise, would necessarily fall within the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Turns out that there isn't anything wrong with the algorithm. I neglected to floatval() the latitude and longitude, which were being passed in to the formula as a string. Hence the odd results. With the floatval, the results are as they should be. Maybe this will help somebody out who finds themselves in a similar situation.

On another note, the geonames zipcode dump that I'm using is definitely missing a number of zipcodes. Does anyone know of a more comprehensive alternative?